# Build error complaining that it cannot find System.Data.Entity in asp.net application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, system.data

I'm building an ASP.net application using Visual Studio Web Developer 2010 Express and have followed the [Nerd Dinner tutorial](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Intro.htm) for a large part. The problem is that when I try to build, it is constantly giving me a build error saying:

> Error 43  Could not load file or
>   assembly 'System.Data.Entity,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified.

This error is coming from the file "ASPNETCOMPILER" apparently. Some things that I have already checked are:

1. There is a reference to System.Data.Entity in the project references already.
2. I have .Net 4.0 installed on the system.

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting back for community goodness, the first comment in this [thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1546705.aspx) by "DonSleza4e" seemed to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the System.Data.Entity.dll into your bin folder, or target your system to use .NET 2.0, as that should copy it over automatically.

Comment: that didn't seem to solve the issue. Copying the dll into the bin folder still makes it complain; besides, this wouldn't solve the problem permanently, if I cleaned my project then the problem would reappear, correct? And I can't really change the target version - it needs to be .net 4.0.